# If the correlation of X and Y is high, the probability of correctly predicting Y from X is also higher?

Tags: correlation, prediction

We usually use the concept of "regression" to describe that variable Y can be predicted from variable X. But can I surmise "correlation" involves the same idea ?

Comment: What does it mean to "correctly predict" something in regression?

Answer (score 0):

Regression slope coefficients are, in essence, partialed correlation coefficients. So there is a strong relationship between the two. However, there is NOT a one-to-one between regression slope coefficients and un-partialed correlation coefficients--the latter can be very misleading, as they are not adjusted for the impact of other predictors.

Correlation coefficients capture linear relations, and will be a poor indicator of nonlinear relationships between X and Y. Regression models are linear in the parameters, but the model can include nonlinear relationships, such as quadratic relations and interactions. In that sense, regression is a more flexible and more informative tool than correlation.